# Weighted $L_2$ Hilbert space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

this is a question where I am trying to find a reference for a result but I haven't been able to find one at all.

Define $L_2(\mathbb R,d\mu) = \{g\in \mathbb R: \int g^2d\mu <\infty\}$. I am trying to find a reference on conditions on $d\mu$ for which $L_2(\mathbb R,d\mu)$ is a Hilbert space with defined inner product

$$
\begin{align*}
\langle f,g\rangle = \int fg d\mu.
\end{align*}
$$

Any help in finding a textbook / paper / reference would be incredibly helpful!

Comment: This is true for any measure. See Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis (http://books.google.com/books/about/Real_and_complex_analysis.html?id=Z_fuAAAAMAAJ) Example 4.5(b) and the proofs referred to there. For any measure space $(X, d\mu)$, $L^2(X,d\mu)$ will always be a Hilbert space. Depending on the measure, it may not be separable, or it may be finite dimensional, but it will always be a Hilbert space.

Comment: if you put this as the answer, I will up vote and mark it as the answer. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true for any measure. See [Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis](http://books.google.com/books/about/Real_and_complex_analysis.html?id=Z_fuAAAAMAAJ) Example 4.5(b) and the proofs referred to there. For any measure space $(X,d\mu)$, $L^2(X,d\mu)$ will always be a Hilbert space. Depending on the measure, it may not be separable, or it may be finite dimensional, but it will always be a Hilbert space.

(Also, the reference works with $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions, but the proofs for $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions are either identical or simpler).